# Using $(this).text with class content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the text of the `click` function to be the last variable, but `$(this).text` doesn't seem to yield such a result. Putting the class at the end gives me both `p` lines. I just want the one I'm clicking on.

Edit:
Sorry for being unclear. Trying to append the text into the input as many times as I click it but only the item that I actually click on. I don't want both to copy over at the same time. So I might click paragraph 1 then paragraph 2 then 1 again without it overwriting

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".p1").click(function() {
    $("input").val(function(index, val) {
      return val + $(this).text
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class=p1>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class=p1>Another paragraph.</p>

<input>
```

Error shows:

```
function(e){return $(this,function(e){return void 0===e?S.text(this):this.empty().each(function(){1!==this.nodeType&&11!==this.nodeType&&9!==this.nodeType||(this.textContent=e)})},null,e,arguments.length)}
```

Comment: It's `$(this).text()` - you have to execute the method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".p1").click(function() {
    $("input").val($("input").val() + $(this).text());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class=p1>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class=p1>Another paragraph.</p>

<input>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Good for one line, need to append one after another while not erasing the previous clicks.

Comment: ok sorry for the misunderstanding, I have added a new line to my answer above just to make it as you want, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this hope so it works

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".p1").click(function() {
    $("input").val($(this).html())
  })
})
```

Comment: This works for just one line within the input (since it overwrites it), I am trying to append. See return val + command. Do I need to + another function?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out. My apologies for the confusion.
var x before the val function worked out well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".p1").click(function() {
    var x = $(event.target).text();
    $("input").val((function(index, val) {
      return val + x

    }))
  })
})
```